# Using wget to fetch password protected website (trac wiki page)

Tags: password, trac, wget

I want to write a bash script that will notify me about changes on a trac wiki timeline. Unfortunately I can't "login" (it needs cookie for next logins).

```
wget http://someserver.com/trac/xxx/login \
--save-cookies=cookies --keep-session-cookies

wget http://someserver.com/trac/xxx/login \
--load-cookies=cookies \ 
--save-cookies=cookies.new --keep-session-cookies\
--post-data=user=viroos&password=myPassword
```

I get:

```
Error 400: Bad Request
```

I also tried --user --password options:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user viroos --password myPassword\ 
https://someserver.com/trac/xxx/timeline?ticket=on&changeset=on&milestone=on&wiki=on&blog=on&max=50&daysback=90&format=rss
```

But this downloads only the login page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are very close to the solution. This should work depending on your configuration:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user viroos --password myPassword \
     --save-cookies=cookies --keep-session-cookies \
     https://someserver.com/trac/xxx/login

wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookies \
     https://someserver.com/trac/xxx/timeline?ticket=on&changeset=on&milestone=on&wiki=on&blog=on&max=50&daysback=90&format=rss
```

First call does the authorization on /login url and saves the auth cookie. The second call should get what you want.

This will work if you have basic autohrization enabled on ..../trac/login url.

Answer (score 1):

The --user/--password flags in wget, for http URLs, cover HTTP basic authentication. Trac has its own login mechanism, so these flags won't work  in this case.

There is a way to do what you want, (although I'm not sure wget is capable of doing it), but before spending time on that direction, did you consider using the [TRAC timeline RSS feed](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRss)?

The RSS feed will allow you to subscribe to the timeline changes, using your favorite  RSS reader, and be notified of them. It will also give you a standard XML file for easy parsing, so you'll be able to do what you want with the data.

Comment: I now about rss time line, in fact I'm trying fetch it (at the end of url I have 50&daysback=90&format=rss). So I will parse XML. I'm doing this because I checking email often then rss reader and because trac authentication doesn't works with google reader so it's little.